# Reset CSS animation with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fullpage.js, animate.css

I'm currently building a website with [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). I'm trying to make the CSS animation in animate.css replay every time I scroll to the section where the element displays.

The problem is: It slides out after I scroll to the next section, but when I go back to that section again, the element is gone and doesn't slide in again.

This is the method I have tried (did not work properly):

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    $('#text').removeClass('animated slideInLeft');
    $('#text').addClass('animated slideOutRight');
  },
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $('#text').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
  }
});
```

```css
#first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#second {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section" id="first">
    <center>
      <p id="text">Something</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="second">
    <h2>Something else</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example.

Comment: And what exactly did not ideally work?

Comment: @Mikey It slides out after I scroll to the next section, but when I go back to that section again, the element is gone and doesn't slide in again.

Comment: [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) may be of assistance.

Comment: @roNn23 Thank you, just added the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can distinguish on which slide you are. After that, you can set the corresponding classes. Look at the example:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
  if(nextIndex === 2) {
    $('#text').addClass('slideOutRight');
  }

  if(index === 2) {
    $('#text').removeClass('slideOutRight');
  }
}
```

Try it:

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if(nextIndex === 2) {
      $('#text').addClass('slideOutRight');
    }
    
    if(index === 2) {
      $('#text').removeClass('slideOutRight');  
    }

    console.log('index:', index, 'nextIndex:', nextIndex, 'direction:', direction);
  },
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $('#text').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
  }
});
```

```css
#first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#second {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section" id="first">
    <center>
      <p id="text">Something</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="second">
    <h2>Something else</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```